# Probability and expected number of steps of/from a transient to an absorbing state in a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-probability

Given an arbitrary but relatively large (more than 50 states) transition matrix, the goal is to find the answer to the following problem:

> Assuming we start at state A and ultimately end up in (the only)
>   absorbing state Z we are looking for a state S that follows:
>
> A → [m steps] → S → [n steps] → Z

*How can I calculate the probability of reaching S before reaching Z and the corresponding expected number of steps (n) from S to Z?*

**Update 24-12:**

So I guess the first part is mosre doable than i thought (if my reasoning is correct). My approach:

1. Rearrange the matrix in canonical form:

   > $P = \left[\begin{matrix}
   > Q & R \\ \mathbf{0} & I
   > \end{matrix}\right]$
2. Find the fundamental matrix:

   > $ N = (I - Q)^{-1} $
3. Find the transient probabilities:

   > $ H = (N - I)N_{dg} $
4. And the row of H which corresponds to starting state A. The entries in this row vector should correspond to the probabilities of reaching A before reaching Z.

** Is my thinking here correct? And how can I condition the original transition matrix P to estimate the steps (n) between A and Z? **

Comment: To clarify, we have a starting state A, ending state Z, and want to find a state S such that, conditioned on passing through S, the expected value of the number of steps to get to S is m, the the number of steps to get to Z is n?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I just don't exactly how to approach such calculation.

Comment: My idea would be that this problem is two-fold: 1. Find the probability of reaching S before absorption, and then 2. Transforming the matrix to the conditional probability as you say. But honestly I don't know exactly how to approach either.

Comment: Are you looking for the probability distribution of the time to absorption for finite discrete or continuous time Markov chain?